# Can't call a view from within a template

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm trying to call a view with an optional parameter from a template, but an exception is thrown.

This is my view:

```
def page(request, page_id=1):
    page = Page.objects.filter(pk=page_id).first()
    context = {
        'page': page,
        'answers': Answer.objects.filter(source_page_id=page.id)
    }
    return render(request, 'page.html', context)
```

And here's my attempt to call it from `page.html` template:

```
<ul>
    {% for answer in answers %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'page' answer.target_page_id %}">{{ answer.choice_text }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

But for some reason, an exception is thrown, as follows:

```
Reverse for 'page' with arguments '(1,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['$$']
```

What's happening here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define input parameters to your view in your urls.py:

This is wrong:

```
url(r"^page/$", page, name="page"),
```

This is right:

```
url(r"^page/(?P<page_id>.*)/$", page, name="page"),
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to change on it:

```
def page(request, pk):
    page = Page.objects.get(pk=1).first()
    context = {
        'page': page,
        'answers': Answer.objects.filter(source_page_id=page__id)
    }
    return render(request, 'page.html', context)
```